# How to create multiple buttons dynamically and handle each one separately

Tags: android, android-button

What I am trying is that, users will push a button and create a new button (button1) will appear and from that button1 they will go to a different activity and you can create more than one.And after that activity is finished, to go back to the activity that started this button. So far I have managed to do that by this code:

```
    new_question = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_question);
    new_question.setOnClickListener(onClick());

private OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView());

            Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Question.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                return;

                }

            });

        }
    };
}

 TextView createNewTextView() {
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button = new Button(this);
    lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.linearLayout2);
    Button.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    Button.setText("New Question");     
    return Button;
}
```

My first problem, it that I don't know how to handle each button differently, because I only create one. On the same hand I don't want to create them beforehand in an xml file, they have to be programmaticaly through the java class.

And Second, after each button is created to be able to see them after. Because after the button is created and I am going through the next activity and then come back (not with the back button, but with an Intent) the buttons are not there.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

just give each Button a `tag`, and assign all of them to the same `onClickListener` which tests whats this Button tag and then make a proper action according to that:

```
mButton.setTag(i);
i++;
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int but_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString().trim());
                    if(but_id == 1){
                        // Do Something   
                    }else if(but_id == 2){
                        // Do Another Something   
                    }
                }

            });
```

---

**UPDATES:**

The tag is just like a label you give to the view in order to refer to it in the future, so, when giving the Buttons a different tags, you are like giving them an IDs, look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html) for further info.

about the Buttons, unfortunately they won't be there when coming back, you have to do one of the following:

1. Recreate them.
2. Pass them with the intent when moving from the activity and pass them again to the activity intent when coming to the activity again then use the data passed to recreate them.
3. Just define them as `static` variables and when coming back to it, re-add them to the corresponding-parent which is in the layout of the activity.

Comment: Can you please explain me how the tag works? 
also are they gonna be there after I return to this activity?

Comment: How can I do the 3rd option?

Answer (score 0):

First, you could add this:

```
// This maps the tag of your button to an Intent to launch a new Activity
private final Map<String,Intent> map = new HashMap<String,Intent>();
// A global listener for your buttons
private final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        String tag = (String) v.getTag();
        Intent i = map.get(tag);
        try{
            startActivity(i);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
            // Log your exception
        }
    }
};
```

Then, this:

```
// This is the method where you create a new button
void createNewButton(String tag,Intent i){
    Button button = new Button(this);
    // blah blah for adding it programatically to the layout
    button.setTag(tag);
    // add the intent for starting the Activity associated 
    // with this Button to the Map
    map.put(tag,intent);
    // add the listener
    button.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

I have added enough comments to make the code self-explanatory.

If you could make-do with a `Long` tag, then you can use [`SparseArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) and save yourself some extra memory used because of `HashMap`.

Comment: I didn't understang the String tag. I mean what String to call.

Comment: @pap It will be a string that uniquely identifies each button. You have to come up with that String :)

Comment: I have tried your code but the button doesn't appear. I am actually a little bit confused of how to use it. Can you give me some explanations? such as if the buttons will be there when I will go again to this activity

Comment: @pap LOL replace the comment with your code to add the button programatically.

Comment: Really, LOL? Can you please tell me how it works because I don't understand? which part of the code, it's a lot you know

Comment: First part goes in your `Activity`. It's global variables. Second part goes in the button handler for the button that the user clicks to add new buttons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70591/discussion-between-pap-and-little-child).